# Oracle PARTITION BY GROUPING_ID with SUM

Tags: sql, oracle, rank, window-functions

I'm trying to implement a simple data warehouse analytic query, dealing with 'YEAR_VALUE', 'MONTH_VALUE' and a 'INVOICE_COST'

```
SELECT YEAR_VALUE, MONTH_VALUE, SUM (INVOICE_VALUE) AS TOTAL_INVOICE,
RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY GROUPING_ID (YEAR_VALUE, MONTH_VALUE) ORDER BY SUM (INVOICE_VALUE) DESC) AS YEAR_RANK,
RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR_VALUE, GROUPING_ID (MONTH_VALUE) ORDER BY SUM (INVOICE_VALUE) DESC) AS MONTH_RANK
FROM FACT_WH
JOIN TIME_WH ON TIME_WH.TIME_ID = FACT_WH.TIME_ID
GROUP BY (YEAR_VALUE, MONTH_VALUE);
```

The output is :
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35b3X.png)

'YEAR_RANK' should express year's total invoice value compared to other years, 2016 has a YEAR_RANK=1 and 2015 has a YEAR_RANK=2

The problem is that 'YEAR_RANK' has the values 1,2,3,4,5 it should be 1,1,2,2,1
I can't find the problem in my code, It's maybe in line #2, I tried everything and wasted much time already.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To answer this type of question, it's always very useful to provide a description of your table structures, provide some sample input data, and then the desired output.  If you can provide a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), that's even better.

Comment: I think your grouping_id for year rank should include the YEAR_VALUE only instead of both YEAR_VALUE and MONTH_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

A good approach, especially in case the query is complex and/or delivers confusing results is to divide the whole query in subqueries each solving a particular task.

In your case I'd recommend to first attack the *join of the fact and dimension table and group by* on YEAR and month to calculate the `total_invoice`

You get results such as

```
YEAR_VALUE MONTH_VALUE TOTAL_INVIOCE
---------- ----------- -------------
      2016           3         29960 
      2016           1         10700 
      2015          11          5100 
      2015           8          1680 
      2016           2           800
```

Note that you don't need any GROUP BY extension such as GROUPING_ID, you'll solve everything using analytic functions

In the next step (using the previous result as a factored subquery) you *calculate the year and months totals* - using analytic version of `SUM`.

In the last step you calculate the RANK. Note that for the year you need
a DENSE_RANK, while otherwise you get 'skipped' ranks such as 1,3 (due to repeated records for one year).

The `year_rank` is not partitioned at all, the `month_rank`is partitioned on YEAR as you order the months within a year.

```
with data as (
-- perform join and group by in this subquery
select 2016 year_value, 3 month_value, 29960 total_invioce from dual union all
select 2016 year_value, 1 month_value, 10700 total_invioce from dual union all
select 2015 year_value, 11 month_value, 5100 total_invioce from dual union all
select 2015 year_value, 8 month_value, 1680 total_invioce from dual union all
select 2016 year_value, 2 month_value, 800 total_invioce from dual),
year_month as (
-- perform year and month summary here
select 
  year_value, month_value, total_invioce,
  sum(total_invioce) over (partition by year_value) total_invoice_year,
  sum(total_invioce) over (partition by month_value) total_invoice_month
from data
)  
-- perform ranking here
select year_value, month_value, total_invioce,
dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY total_invoice_year DESC) year_rank,
rank() OVER (partition by year_value ORDER BY total_invoice_month DESC)  month_rank
from year_month
order by total_invioce desc;

YEAR_VALUE MONTH_VALUE TOTAL_INVIOCE  YEAR_RANK MONTH_RANK
---------- ----------- ------------- ---------- ----------
      2016           3         29960          1          1 
      2016           1         10700          1          2 
      2015          11          5100          2          1 
      2015           8          1680          2          2 
      2016           2           800          1          3
```